# Unknown contractions and grammar in harsh language using 置いてくもん

Tags: grammar, contractions

I'm playing a game and I came across a dialog where a person says:

```
置いてくもん置いてきゃ
許してやらなくもないぜオラァ！
```

And I'm having a difficult time understanding how this grammar was formed. I am mainly lost on the `置いてくもん置いてきゃ` part. I do not understand what `置いてくもん` is at all and it seems like `置いてきゃ` was formed by doing:

```
置いていく　→　置いていけば　→　置いていきゃ　→　置いてきゃ

If you leave...
```

So what is and how is the `置いてくもん` part formed?

My translation overall is something like:

```
You better leave... If you leave...
Well then perhaps we can forgive you!
```

Background context of the situation:

During this part of the game a cutscene is played where you are running down a path and ram into a group of 3 people. You knock them all down to the ground in the process. Once they get up, they show their anger and say the above. Ultimately the game puts you into a fight with them where you must beat them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 置いてくもん置いてきゃ

It's a colloquial, contracted pronunciation of

> 置いていくものを置いていけば
> "If you leave what you (are supposed to) leave"

It consists of:

置いていく(置いて行く) ⇒ 置いてく
もの(物) ⇒ もん
を is left out
置いていけば(置いて行けば) ⇒ 置いてきゃ

置いてく is a relative clause that modifies もん.
［置いてく］もん literally means "things [that you leave]".

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it safe to treat this 〜てやらなくもないぜ construction as a more indirect way of expressing てやるぜ?

Comment: @user26484 You may want to read: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/70537/9831 It's like saying ～してやってもいいんだぜ in a condescending manner.